# Static to Dynamic nature in C

Tags: c, naivebayes

I have implemented naive Bayes but I did it in static memory allocation.
I wanted to convert into dynamic but my small brain is not able to do that.

```
#define COLS 4 //including class label
#define BINS 100 
#define CLASS_COL 0
#define CLASS 2
```

The idea is to fetch above value from a configuration file and then set it.

```
struct each_col //Probability for each feature based on classes
{
    double col_PB[BINS][CLASS];
};  
struct NB_Class_Map
{
    char label[250];
    unsigned int label_value;
    double class_PB;
};
struct NB //Proabability for entire feature
{
    struct NB_Class_Map classes[CLASS];
    struct each_col cols[COLS];
};
NB nb = {0}; //gloabal value
```

The function to train NB:

```
long strhash(const char *str)
{
    long hash = 5381;
    int c;
    printf("IN: %s ",str);
    while (c = *str++)
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */

     printf("OUT: %ld  ||",hash);
    return hash;
}

int setup_train_NB(vector<vector<string> > &data)
{
    //Finding the feature count
    static int class_label = -1;
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<data.size();i++)
    {
        unsigned int Class;
        printf("\n===========New ROW==============\n");
        int k;
        for(k=0;k<CLASS;k++)
        {
            if(strcmp(data[i][CLASS_COL].c_str(), nb.classes[k].label) == 0)
            {
                printf("MATCHED\n");
                Class = nb.classes[k].label_value;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(k==CLASS)
        {
            printf("NOT MATCHED\n");
            class_label++;
            nb.classes[class_label].label_value = class_label;
            strcpy( nb.classes[class_label].label, data[i][CLASS_COL].c_str());
            Class = nb.classes[class_label].label_value;
        }

        printf("Class: %d  ||\n", Class);

        for(unsigned j=0;j<data[0].size();j++)
        {
            printf("\n===========New COLUMN==============\n");
            if(j == CLASS_COL)
            {
                nb.classes[Class].class_PB++;
                continue;
            }
            unsigned int bin = strhash((data[i][j].c_str()))%BINS;

            printf("Bin: %d  ||", bin);
            printf("Class: %d  ||\n", Class);
            nb.cols[j].col_PB[bin][Class]++; //[feature][BINS][CLASS]
        }
    }

    //Finding the feature PB
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<COLS;i++)
    {
        if(i==CLASS_COL)
            continue;
        for(unsigned j=0;j<BINS;j++)
        {
            for(unsigned k=0;k<CLASS;k++)
            {
//              nb.cols[i].col_PB[j][k] /= nb.classes[k].class_PB; //without laplacian smoothing
                nb.cols[i].col_PB[j][k] = (nb.cols[i].col_PB[j][k] + 1) / (nb.classes[k].class_PB + COLS - 1); //with laplace smoothing
            }
        }
    }

    int k = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    while(k<CLASS)
    {
        sum += nb.classes[k].class_PB;
        k++;
    }

//Finding the class PB
    k = 0;
    while(k<CLASS)
    {
        nb.classes[k].class_PB /= sum;
        k++;
    }
return 0;
}
```

The program is supposed to be written in C but for the moment, I use vector to fetched the data from a CSV file. Please ignore that for the moment. The actual question is how I can remove those hardcoded define value and still declare my structs.

Although it does not matter but the CSV file look like this and it may change in terms of no of cols and labels. The first line is ignored and not put into data.

```
Person,height,weight,foot
male,654,180,12
female,5,100,6
female,55,150,8
female,542,130,7
female,575,150,9
```

What actually I am doing is, for each value is put into a bin, then for each of those value, I am finding proabability for the CLASS/label i.e male = 0, female = 1

Comment: The fact that you are using `vector` and it works may mean that you actually want to use C++ rather than C. In C++, working with arrays and dynamic allocation is easier, so if you can use C++, do it. If so, you might want to change the tags in your question.

Comment: No, I have to use C. This naive Bayes thing is just a small piece of a large puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

Basically:

- Define variables instead of preprocessor macro constants: `size_t cols; size_t bins;` etc.
- Replace your 1-dimensional fixed-size arrays with pointers (initialized to `NULL`!) and length variables. Alternatively, you could use a `struct mytype_span { size_t length; mytype* data; }`
- Replace your 2-dimensional fixes-size arrays with "1-dimensional" pointers (also initialized to `NULL` of course) and pairs off dimension variables. Again, you could use a struct.
- Replace your 2-d array accesses `a[x][y]` with a "linearized" access, i.e. `a[x * row_length_of_a + y]` (or you could do this in an inline function which takes the relevant arguments, or a `struct mytype_span`)
- When you've read your configuration values from, um, wherever - set the relevant length variables (see above).
- use the `malloc()` library function to allocate the correct amount of space; remember to check the `malloc()` return value to make sure it's not null, before using the pointer values!

Comment: set the relevant length variables ? could you explain a little more.

Comment: @RoshanMehta: Edited.

Comment: Oops, sorry, edited the wrong reply (I need to find how to cancel)

Answer (score 0):

Your use of struct, is probably wrong, except for `struct NB_Class_Map`. You shouldn't use struct in the goal of puting big arrays in the same variable. Instead of this, you should define of variable for each array, not putting it inside a struct, and instead of using array, replace it by a pointer. Then you can allocate memory to your pointer. e.g. :

```
struct mydata {
    type1 field1;
    type2 field2;
    etc...
    } *myarray;
myarray = calloc(number_of_record_you_need, sizeof(struct mydata));
// here, error checking code, etc.
```

Now, having done that, if you really want, you may put your different pointers into a global structure, but each of your table should be allocated separately.

---

Edit (about your variables) :
`NB` has no real interest as a structure. It's just 2 variables you glued together:

```
struct NB_Class_Map classes[CLASS];
struct each_col cols[COLS];
```

`NB.Cols` is not really a structure. It's just a three dimensional array

```
double cols[COLS][BINS][CLASS];
```

The only real structure is

```
struct NB_Class_Map
{
    char label[250];
    unsigned int label_value;
    double class_PB;
};
```

So you just have to replace

```
struct NB_Class_Map classes[CLASS];
```

with

```
struct NB_Class_Map *classes;
```

and

```
double cols[COLS][BINS][CLASS];
```

with

```
double *cols[BINS][CLASS];
```

Or if you want a type name :

```
typedef double each_col[BINS][CLASS];
each_cols *cols;
```

and allocate memory space for `classes` and `colls` with `calloc`.

Now, if you really want this `struct NB` :

```
typedef double each_col[BINS][CLASS];

struct NB
{
    struct NB_Class_Map *classes;
    each_col *cols;
};
```

Comment: I didn't understand you.

Comment: What don't you understand ?

Comment: Could you convert my structs into what you are saying

Comment: I still need to #define BINS and CLASS ? By the way I understood what you were telling.

Comment: Well, since BINS and CLASS must be defined (have a value), the only way to define each_col with BINS and CLASS being variables, is to make it inside a function, but then, you can't use this type declaration in the parameter list of a function (since this happens at compile time). The only way to do it if you wan't to use your variables here and there in your program, would be to pass a pointer to double, to pass BINS and CLASS (or to make them global), to repeat your typedef and cast in to cols in every function which needs to use it.

Comment: In fact this is just synctactic sugar for the manual calculation as Einpoklum proposed in his answer.